# Restrict width on element to width of first child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a pretty tricky situation here which I am trying to solve with CSS only.

Basically, the idea is extremely simple, I have an `.item` div which holds an `img` and a `p`.
The image cannot be taller than 320px, so I added `max-height: 320px`, in order to maintain aspect ratio, it also has `width: auto`.

So far so good...

The tricky part is: **the parent `.item` div, must have the same width as the `img`**

But because the `p` contains text which spans wider than the image, it doesn't work.

I have created a JS Bin here: http://jsbin.com/liyeratuzadu/1/edit
In this JS Bin, look for the following code in the CSS tab:

```
.item p {
  /*width: 100px;*/
}
```

Uncomment the line to see the desired result.

Tip: Don't wanna have a fixed width on the `p` as I don't think that is very responsive.

Comment: Is the img responsive or has it a fixed width?

Comment: @gruberb hey it's repsonsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution #1 - The display:table method

1) Set `display:table` on the item

2) Give it a very small width say `width: 1px`

```
.item {
  display: table;
  width: 1px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

**[Updated JsBin](http://jsbin.com/jaxorodeduji/1/)**

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.item {
  display: table;
  width: 1px;
  background: tomato;
}
.item img {
  display: block;
  /* removes spacing from inline-block (default) */
  width: auto;
  max-height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x700/">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea impedit labore atque illo autem inventore totam, voluptatem tempore repudiandae.</p>
</div>
```

### Solution #2 - Make use of intrinsic sizing (not IE compatible)

```
.item {
  width: -moz-min-content; 
  width: -webkit-min-content; 
  width: min-content;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: min-content;
  background: tomato;
}
.item img {
  display: block;
  /* removes spacing from inline-block (default) */
  width: auto;
  max-height: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/500x700/">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea impedit labore atque illo autem inventore totam, voluptatem tempore repudiandae.</p>
</div>
```

1) [Browser support is quite good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) (except for IE)

2) [Here's an article](http://demosthenes.info/blog/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-MinContent) explaining the `min-content` property