# On image hover - add a caption which takes the width of the image

Tags: html, css, hover

Okay. So what I'm trying to do is make it so that when I hover over an image, the image changes from black and white/greyscale to color as well as show text in the bottom, which is a hyperlink. I have this so far.

Since I couldn't figure out how to use the stackoverflow code thing, I will link to my web page. [enter link description here](http://masterwhisker.com/test/)

Thanks. :)

Comment: any code what you have worked?

Comment: Sorry, accidentally pressed enter. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your anchor initially with `display: none` and then on hover set it to `display: block`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/d1nae4we/2/)**

NB: In order to get the width of the anchor to suit the img width - without manually fixing a width on the container div - I have used one of the techniques that I described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26158301/703717).

### Markup

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" />
    <a href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    display:table;
    width: 1px;
}
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    -ms-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
a {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -45px;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 0 0 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:hover a {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. (Sorry if I didn't make it clear what I wanted), what I was looking for was something like this http://www.firepowerrecords.com/artists/ but with the greyscale effect. How would I go about that? Thx.

Comment: @Akshay - Thanks - I fixed that by wrapping the img and `a` in a div and by targettting hover on the `div`

Comment: @Danield How would I go about making the hyperlink appear similar to on http://www.firepowerrecords.com/artists/ but still with the greyscale to color effect?

Comment: @Danield Thank you so much! This has helped phenomenally!

Comment: @AppleMan - No problem. Also, I edited the title of your question to better describe what you needed.

Comment: @Danield, as I'm completely new to stackoverflow, how do set the correct answer?